# Clone private GitHub repo in Google Cloud Build yaml

Tags: github, ssh, google-cloud-platform, yaml, google-cloud-build

According to a [note](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/access-private-github-repos) in Cloud Build documentation titled *Accessing private GitHub repositories*:

> When you run builds using Cloud Build triggers, you can automatically connect to any private repository you own without storing your credentials in Secret Manager.

Based on this, I have tried to `git clone` my private GitHub repo (without piping ssh keys from Secret Manager to ssh files which the doc states is unnecessary using a build trigger) to no avail. Using ssh below in my `cloudbuild.yaml` file:

```
steps:
- name: google/cloud-sdk:alpine
  id: Clone repo
  entrypoint: git
  args: ['clone', 'git@github.com:my-org/my-repo.git']
```

results in error:

```
Step #0: Host key verification failed.
Step #0: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

And using https

```
  args: ['clone', 'https://github.com/my-org/my-repo.git']
```

I get:

```
Step #0 - "Clone repo": fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
```

Is there any way to clone a private GitHub repo within `cloudbuild.yaml` without tediously piping ssh keys from Secret Manager to volumes before the clone? Any tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand. The note you added is intended for triggers in Cloud Build, do you want your build triggered by a Cloud build trigger (in this case what you're doing is not necessary) or manually?

Comment: Yes, a cloudbuild.yaml is necessary whether you use a trigger or build on the CLI. My cloudbuild.yaml file is in a private GitHub repository. The build is triggered whenever a specific tag is pushed. Within my build (configured in cloudbuild.yaml), I must clone the git repository, edit it, and push it again.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar case that has been created as an issue in [github](https://github.com/docker-library/golang/issues/148) which can help you to resolve your errors while using ssh.

For https approach, I would recommend you to remove https://github.com from the url.
And I found another issue that has been created in [github](https://github.community/t/clone-private-repo/1371) which can help you to resolve your issue while using https approach.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [note](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/access-private-github-repos) shared, You need to configure your [Cloud Build Trigger](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/create-manage-triggers#connect_repo), if you want to avoid Secret Manager.

The Build Trigger setup step involves authenticating to your source repository with your username and password.

So when you fire this Cloud Build Trigger, it will not ask for your credentials in Secret Manager, as the authentication is already provided in an earlier step (Trigger Setup).